# Rebending a bumper

Tags: body

I've got a '99 Ranger which ran over a metal sign post. Squashed the post (we did notify the people responsible for the post). The only damage  to the Ranger is a slightly bent chrome bumper. I'd like to re-bend the bumper if its easy enough. Has anyone bent a bumper back into shape? How did you do it?

I was thinking of some lethal combination of clamps, wooden blocks, and a come-along. However, I thought it would be wise to ask here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I straightened a chrome bumper that was pushed into the fender using a tree and a 3/8" tow chain. I hooked the chain on the bumper then put a wrap of chain around the tree. I backed up slowly on an asphalt driveway to limit tire spin. You have to pull a little past the ideal point as it will spring back some when the tension is released. It wasn't perfect when done but looked better than when bent.

Comment: And did you have any problems with the chrome delaminating?

Comment: I didn't at the time. However this was on a 84' Dodge D250 that was 16 years old at the time. I don't know if your bumper has the same quality chrome. But if the bumper is bent that bad the chrome may flake at the bent anyway.

Comment: I might try something like this. Let's see if I can pull a tree over on the pickup :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've only straightened out small pieces but every time I used a hammer, something smooth and of the correct shape to hammer against and lots of patience. I would be worried about the chrome though. It's only a small layer on the surface and bending/hammering at it will remove it easily, and then your bumper will start to rust. You might have better luck going to nearby junkyards to look for an intact bumper.

Answer (score 0):

I have an 89 ranger with a bent bumper, however, I didn't kill a sign with mine
 Keep in mind, when using a chain, make sure that the tree you use to pull against is big enough and the chain is securely wrapped so it won't come unhooked when pulling. If it comes undone at the tree (as I have seen once) that chain will come back at you like a rubber band, go through your wind shield and take your head clean off your shoulders...just. something to think about.